# Detect in Xcode iPhone project whether I'm building for simulator or device?

Tags: iphone, xcode, target

Is there any way I can conditionally compile in my app based upon whether I'm building for the simulator or the device? (My app hooks to an external server: if I'm running on the device, I want to connect to localhost; if I'm running on the device, I want to go to my production server.)

I'm looking for some #ifdef variable I can detect, or even something at runtime...doesn't matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
```

or, alternatively,

```
#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
```

will tell you if you're running on the device. In order for it to work, you must

`#include "TargetConditionals.h"`

file that you can find [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/TargetConditionals.h).

Comment: Thanks...that seems to work.

Any way to find out what else is defined in "TargetConditionals.h"? I can't find the file anywhere...

Comment: Correction...your second example (TARGET_OS_IPHONE) always succeeds, provided, of course, you're doing iPhone development. Your first example, TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR, is what I'm looking for, and that only succeeds if you're running on the simulator (vs. the device.)

Comment: Edited with a link to the file.

Comment: I've never included that file and TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR always seems to work - it could already be included by the foundation.

Answer (score 1):

I created a macro in which you can specify which actions you want to perform inside parentheses and these actions will only be performed if the device is being simulated.

```
#define SIM(x) if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice].model lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"simulator"].location != NSNotFound){x;}
```

This is used like this:

```
SIM(NSLog(@"This will only be logged if the device is simulated"));
```